# VSphere and Fog

Tags: ruby, fog, vsphere

Trying and trying to do something very simple in fog 1.9 with the vsphere provider. The examples in the little documentation there is not working for me.

I want to list all VMs in a folder. Simple eh?

Tried...

```
credentials = {
    :provider => "vsphere",
    :vsphere_username => user,
    :vsphere_password=> pass,
    :vsphere_server => "vc_name",
    :vsphere_ssl    => true,
    :vsphere_expected_pubkey_hash => "1466f20c1b3f990a2a018dc2ca22a79fc2d0284ab4aac534c47blah"
}

compute = Fog::Compute.new(credentials)
vms = compute.servers.all('folder' => '/Datacenters/Ewl/Self-Service')

pp vms
```

This connects and churns away and RETURNS ALL VMs IN THE DATACENTER and not just the folder. Grr.

I've tried lots of variations on the folder variable e.g.

```
vms = compute.servers.all('folder' => '/Hosts & Clusters/Ewl1_vm/Self-Service')
vms = compute.servers.all('folder' => 'Self-Service')
vms = compute.servers.all('folder' => 'Self-Service','datacenter' => 'Ewl')
```

But all do the same thing.

I've worked through the code and it's not helped me really.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what your datacenter and folder name are, then the simple way to do this is:

```
vms = compute.list_virtual_machines(datacenter: 'Ewl', folder: 'Self-Service')
```

'folder' in the .servers.all filter hypothetically should work, but you are bound to find surprises with hidden paths, more than 1 datacenter, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @greymouser. I was shocked when I saw your take on defining the hash. I thought I'd got it really wrong! However tried it and got this...   

`test1.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
...t_virtual_machines(datacenter: 'Ewl', folder: 'Self-Service'...
                              ^
test1.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
...al_machines(datacenter: 'Ewl', folder: 'Self-Service')`

The examples use a rocket =>

Comment: Yeah, just use the old style hash if that's what your your version of Ruby supports. Besides that, the above code should work for you.

Comment: **YAY** Using 1.9 now and it works! Cheers @greymouser 1-up .

Comment: Created gist to complete answer [https://gist.github.com/jimfdavies/4976886](https://gist.github.com/jimfdavies/4976886)